# How to specify the output format for a WFS service using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, output

I'm using GeoServer 2.20.3 and I've got a published layer for which I want to set two output formats.

I've searched up and down in layer edits, in the WFS services tab, in the user's manual... and I'm unable to find the solution. Where should I specify the output formats?

Comment: Possible output formats are documented in https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html. You seem to want something special.

Comment: You're right @user30184. Question edited.

Comment: Interesting, but maybe you cannot limit the WFS output formats. It is possible to limit the supported WMS image formats in the WMS service settings (Allowed MIME Types) but there is not any similar setting in the WFS service settings. You must perhaps filter the requests with the web server (and edit also GetCapabilities if you want it to show a correct list of formats). Or try to contact some developer who could implement a new feature.

Comment: since you can convert GML (or GeoJSON) into almost any format it makes no sense to limit the WFS output formats.